# How to add a customer with custom fields to Quickbooks POS using QBPOSXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, qbxml

So my problem is pretty simple: I am trying to add a customer to Quickbooks using ASP.NET and QBWebConnector, and thankfully I am succeeding. The problem occurs when I try to add custom fields to the customer.

Here's the `qbposxml` I am sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbposxml version="3.0"?>
<QBPOSXML>
   <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
      <CustomerAddRq requestID="1">
         <CustomerAdd>
            <Salutation>Mr.</Salutation>
            <FirstName>Ammar</FirstName>
            <LastName>Ahmed</LastName>
            <BillAddress>
               <Street>asascc, asdas</Street>
            </BillAddress>
            <Phone>03321221221</Phone>
         </CustomerAdd>
      </CustomerAddRq>
      <DataExtModRq>
         <DataExtMod>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>IDNumber</DataExtName>
            <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
            <ListObjRef>
               <FullName>Ammar Ahmed</FullName>
            </ListObjRef>
            <DataExtValue>12331</DataExtValue>
         </DataExtMod>
      </DataExtModRq>
      <DataExtModRq>
         <DataExtMod>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>GebDatum</DataExtName>
            <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
            <ListObjRef>
               <FullName>Ammar Ahmed</FullName>
            </ListObjRef>
            <DataExtValue>21/22/12</DataExtValue>
         </DataExtMod>
      </DataExtModRq>
   </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBPOSXML>
```

Now the response I get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QBPOSXML>
   <QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
      <CustomerAddRs requestID="1" statusCode="0" statusMessage="Status OK" statusSeverity="Info">
         <CustomerRet>
            <ListID>755269278256496897</ListID>
            <TimeModified>2017-03-08T14:00:42+05:00</TimeModified>
            <AccountBalance>0.00</AccountBalance>
            <AccountLimit>0.00</AccountLimit>
            <CustomerDiscPercent>0.00</CustomerDiscPercent>
            <CustomerDiscType>None</CustomerDiscType>
            <FirstName>Ammar</FirstName>
            <FullName>Mr. Ammar Ahmed</FullName>
            <IsAcceptingChecks>True</IsAcceptingChecks>
            <IsUsingWithQB>False</IsUsingWithQB>
            <LastName>Ahmed</LastName>
            <Phone>03321221221</Phone>
            <PriceLevelNumber>1</PriceLevelNumber>
            <Salutation>Mr.</Salutation>
            <StoreExchangeStatus>Modified</StoreExchangeStatus>
            <BillAddress>
               <Street>asascc, asdas</Street>
            </BillAddress>
         </CustomerRet>
      </CustomerAddRs>
      <DataExtModRs statusCode="20036" statusMessage="Extension error (ListID is missing)" statusSeverity="Error">
         <DataExtRet />
      </DataExtModRs>
   </QBPOSXMLMsgsRs>
</QBPOSXML>
```

I don't know how to get the `ListID` of the customer I am adding since it is created *after* the customer is added.

Thing to note: Customer is added but without custom fields. From [this](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Customer_with_Custom_Fields) and [this](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/ka2G0000000XacQIAS/QBSDK-Custom-fields) I gathered that I didn't need ListID.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update:**
So after the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42674250/6414944) by **William Lorfing**, I checked out Chapter 6 of QBPOS Programmer's Guide and discovered **macros**. Here's how I ended up using them, with outstanding results:

**My CustomerAdd Request became:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbposxml version="3.0"?>
<QBPOSXML>
   <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
      <CustomerAddRq requestID="1">
         <CustomerAdd defMacro="ListID:Cust1"> NOTICE THE INITIALIZATION OF MACRO!
            <Salutation>Mr.</Salutation>
            <FirstName>Ammar</FirstName>
            <LastName>Ahmed</LastName>
            <BillAddress>
               <Street>asascc, asdas</Street>
            </BillAddress>
            <Phone>03321221221</Phone>
         </CustomerAdd>
      </CustomerAddRq>
      <DataExtModRq>
         <DataExtMod>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>IDNumber</DataExtName>
            <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
            <ListObjRef>
               <ListID useMacro="ListID:Cust1" /> NOTICE THE USE OF MACRO!
            </ListObjRef>
            <DataExtValue>12331</DataExtValue>
         </DataExtMod>
      </DataExtModRq>
      <DataExtModRq>
         <DataExtMod>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>GebDatum</DataExtName>
            <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
            <ListObjRef>
               <ListID useMacro="ListID:Cust1" /> NOTICE THE USE OF MACRO!
            </ListObjRef>
            <DataExtValue>21/22/12</DataExtValue>
         </DataExtMod>
      </DataExtModRq>
   </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBPOSXML>
```

First we initialize the macro and then we use it, thus avoiding additional request and don't know how many lines of useless code just to add custom fields.

Thanks **William Lorfing** for the hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For QBPOS SDK, ListObjRef required ListID and not fullname.

You will either have to do the customeradd and then in the next request do the DataExtAdd with the ListID or you can try using Macros. See Chapter 6 of the POS SDK Programmers Guide.
The guide is included in the POS SDK.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint! I used macros and it is working flawlessly now. Thanks again.